# is there a way to fill NAs until meet a condition in a row and move all the values forward in r

Tags: r

The sample data is like this:

```
temp <- data.frame(c1 = c(NA, 1, NA, NA), c2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), c3 = c(NA, 20, NA, 2), c4 = c(8, NA, 100, NA), c5 = c(10, 2, 4, NA))
temp
  c1 c2 c3  c4 c5
1 NA  1 NA   8 10
2  1  1 20  NA  2
3 NA  1 NA 100  4
4 NA  1  2  NA NA
```

And this is what I want to get:

```
   c1 c2 c3  c4 c5
1   8 10 NA  NA NA
2  20 NA  2  NA NA
3 100  4 NA  NA NA
4  NA NA NA  NA NA
```

Using > 5 as the condition for each row, to first change all the values to NA if not meet the > 5 conditions and then move all the values in the row forward.

`apply(temp, 1, function(x) {if (all(is.na(x))) {NA} else {which.max(x > 5)} })` could find the first value but I couldn't find a way to change all before to NA and move the rest forward without many `for` loops, would you have any suggestions on this?

Comment: I couldn't understand what's the transformation that you want

Comment: @RicardoSemiãoeCastro, in row 1, c1, c2, and c3's values are not greater than 5, so we remove them and move c4 and c5's values 8 and 10 forward to the first column and second column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an option

```
t(apply(temp, 1, function(x) {
      i1 <- which(x > 5)[1]
     if(!is.na(i1)) {
     x[seq_len(i1-1)] <- NA
    `length<-`(x[i1:length(x)], length(x))
     } else rep(NA, length(x))}))
```

-output

```
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    8   10   NA   NA   NA
#[2,]   20   NA    2   NA   NA
#[3,]  100    4   NA   NA   NA
#[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Comment: Thank you, the `which(x > 5)[1]` part is superb, I didn't think about `[1]`. And to maintain all the values as numeric, should I change `x[i1:length(x)]` to `as.numeric(x[i1:length(x)])`?

Comment: @Y.Z.  With `apply`, it is already converting to a matrix and matrix can have only single type.  So, if the columns are all numeric, then you don't need the `as.numeric`.  If it was type specific, I would change the `rep(NA` to `rep(NA_real_` and the assignment to `NA_real_`

Comment: Thanks again, I just realized my original data format was char (maybe because of all the NAs), but your code is still amazingly fine with it.

Comment: @Y.Z. if some columns are character class, then with `apply`, it converts the whole data to `character` because `matrix` can have only single class.  Can you update your post with a realistic example

Comment: No worries, those are minor problems. Thanks again for your help.